# Prevent certain HTML elements from being copied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not entirely sure how to go about researching this idea. I'm sure it's been done, but I'm having an issue articulating it for an effective Google search.

I have a results page that has the option to download the results to a csv. But I imagine there being times when a user would rather just copy and paste the visible results on the page. How can I get it so when they copy/paste, it only displays the results and not the headings.

```
<h1>results #1</h1>
<p>here are all of your awesome results</p>
<p>here are all of your awesome results</p>
<span> showing 2 of 2 </span>
```

So in my example code, they would copy just the `<p>` elements & not the `<h1>` or `<span>`.

I assume it'll be a javascript/jquery solution, which I'm fine with. But not really even sure where to start with it. Can this be reasonably accomplished?

Comment: I think you want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: Very nice. `user-select` is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize CSS had an option. If you submit more of a formal answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`user-select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) property to disable text highlighting on the `<h1>` and `<span>`

```
h1, span {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C6KWy/

Comment: If you press `ctrl+A` in Firefox you will appear to select all of the text (all of it highlights), but a quick copy/paste into notepad shows that only the selectable text is copied.  Cool!

Comment: This doesn't work really though. See http://jsfiddle.net/ao3m0emr/. Select from "paragraph" and down to the end. Paste somewhere. All of the text was copied.

Comment: This has been fixed in Chrome.

Comment: @AdamLynch 's example still reproduces the text being copied on modern Chrome 121.0.6167.139